# Home Appliances and Energy Usage

Tags: data-request, energy

I'm looking for a dataset of home appliances and their energy usage. I'm not picky if it is by hour or averaged by the day, but would like it to be broken down by type, brand, and the energy usage for a particular model or an item. For example:

Type: Refrigerator

Brand: Samsung

Model: abc123

Energy usage: 100 kwh